# Printing logos on flex/vinyl banners

Tags: print-design, logo, print-production, file-format

I am creating an artwork that will be produced as flex/vinyl banners. My client wants to include a bunch of logos. All those logos (size: medium/high) are downloaded from the web. Is it alright to use those logos directly in the artwork?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the size of the banner, but generally, unless they are all in a vector format (AI, EPS, SVG) — which ensures the sharpest quality — they will not be good enough to print.

Many times people get logos from the internet and they are low resolution JPG or PNG files which can generally work for a Powerpoint, but not for print.

If you're concerned about the *right* to use these logos, better check that with your client. Most commercial companies have their own policies about who & how should use their branding, unless they're partnering with your client, in which case its probably fine.

Comment: Thank you. They are my client's partners. So, no issue there. Shall request for vector files. But, will high-res jpegs work?

Comment: High-res is a relative term, so can't answer that. Maybe!

Answer (score 0):

If your banner is to be printed directly on the vinyl, you'll want the highest resolution you can get for the images. Small images when enlarged to the size required for a banner will become pixelated.

As Lucian suggests, vector format is preferred, especially if you are going to have the graphics created from adhesive vinyl using a sign cutter or similar device. The vendor will almost always require it to be in vector format or will charge a premium to convert it.

Additionally, you can accept a high resolution bitmap and trace it with any number of programs, including free Inkscape, to create a suitable vector image for your banner. Tracing a high resolution bitmap into a vector file provides more accurate representation of the image than tracing a low resolution bitmap.

Of course, if the client provides vector images from square one, all is good.

Answer (score 0):

> All those logos (size: medium/high)

Medium and high is not a measure to measure measurable logos :o)

One more adequate is pixels. How many pixels does the logo have? 100x100px? 1000x1000px? More? is the logo on SVG format?

> are downloaded from the web

There is no such thing as "from the web". You could have a repository of high-resolution logos, the logo could be the one used on the web page but not optimized for it so it could be humungous...

Is the resolution enough when viewed at the desired size and print resolution?

That is the real question and you need to answer it yourself. Take your logo. paste it on a design program and take a ruler to have physical dimensions. Is that ok? then you are good to go. Does it look like a mashed potato? Then get one better.

[Google this](https://www.google.com/search?q=logo%20high%20resolution&rlz=1C1GKLA_enMX664MX664&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNSyVL-UZ5P2WMjVHlZmXDJpiT_sKw:1578598919901&source=lnt&tbs=isz:l&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju9POeo_fmAhUDXa0KHZS9CsMQpwUIJA&biw=2048&bih=806&dpr=1.25) and compare. They work. You have even some vectorized. If you can not get one better vectorize it yourself.